# JQuery.getJSON and use returned data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I use a little modified function, which is repeated in several tutorials or used like answer in some forums.

Problem is that after call function, nothing heppens. I debug it and JavaScript function is call correctly, Controller is call correctly too, but i don't why, dropdownlist is not updated.

It seems that problem is somewhere in functions nested into jQuery.getJSON, but i don't know how to debug and check it or how check that data are realy send correctly from server or catched by client.

JavaScript:

```
function ConnectedEndPoint(href, SwitchId) {
        jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        var id = jQuery(href).attr('id');
        var index = '_' + id.split('_')[1] + '_' + id.split('_')[2];
        jQuery.getJSON('/ActiveItem/Switches/ConnectedEndPoint/Switch/' + SwitchId, function (data) {
            var items = "<OPTION>---------------------</OPTION>";
            jQuery.each(data, function (i, _switch) {
                items += "<OPTION value='" + _switch.Value + "'>" + _switch.Text + "</OPTION>";
            });
            jQuery("#item_City" + index).html(items);
        });
    };
```

Controller:

```
    class mySwitchBoard
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public JsonResult ConnectedEndPoint(string locality, int id)
        {
            IRepository<Switch> _SwitchRepository = new Repository<Switch>();
            Switch _Switch = _SwitchRepository.Get(id);
            IList<mySwitchBoard> mySB = new List<mySwitchBoard>();
            foreach (SwitchBoard sb in _Switch.Location.ServerRoom.SwitchBoards)
            {
                mySB.Add(new mySwitchBoard() { Text = sb.Name, Value = sb.Id.ToString() });
            }
            Repository).GetAllInServerRoom(2);
            return Json(mySB);
        }
```

View is little spagetti code, but result is something like this:

```
<button name="itemUp_0_0" onclick="ConnectedEndPoint(this, 123)" type="button">Up</button><br>
<select id="item_City_0_0" name="item_City_0_0"></select>
```

Comment: Is that your actual code? Because it looks like you have an extra line in there that would be a javascript error or at least end your function earlier than you want.

Comment: sorry, i did some cosmetic changes after copy-paste, i check it

Comment: Have you tried debugging in Firefox with FireBug with a breakpoint set in the getJSON callback to see what data is returned?  or the IE developer tools, though I find FF/FB to be easier to use.

Comment: now it should be OK, i didn't delete all commented code which was wraped to next row

Comment: No. I used only VisualStudio and in IE i has somewhere set to be able debug pages. I try it.

Comment: You've introduced a potential XSS vulnerability with your handling of switch options. You should instead define `items = [];` and do something like this: `items.push(new Option(_switch.Text, _switch.Value);` and then add them as children to the `<select>`. Also, please consider using Firefox or Chrome to develop the site. IE (pre-9) is terrible with developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your call to getJSon is failing because the data you are trying to retrieve with it is not serializable. I know IList is not, but your mySwitchBoard should be. Try changing IList to just List.

The following code should help with debugging

```
$.ajaxSetup({"error":function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {   
      alert(textStatus);
      alert(errorThrown);
      alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
  }});
```

Comment: Thanks to much. IList is OK, but this javascript function was helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in Controller:

```
...
JsonResult jr = Json(mySB, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
...
```

JsonRequestBehavior wasn't set to AllowGet